# Why does my address bar keep getting selected on MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

I recently got a 2018 MacBook Pro.  Everything is great but I find that when I start typing in my browser (primarily Chrome) the cursor will regularly jump to the address bar.  At first I thought maybe I was hitting the trackpad with my hand but the cursor is no where near the address bar.  Then I thought maybe I'm hitting the Touchbar with my fingers, but again, my hands are no where near the numbers even, much less the Touchbar.

I'm proficient power user who regularly uses keyboard shortcuts to get around my computer, but I can't figure out what's going on here.  This never happened with my old MacBook Pro.  Any ideas?

Comment: `⌘ + I` will jump to the address bar. If you're not accidentally hitting that keyboard shortcut, then I have no idea. I guess you can try to pay more attention and see if that's what you're doing.

Comment: I think you mean ⌘ + L, right?  I don't think that's what I'm hitting.  I use that keyboard shortcut all the time.  That's why I'm confused!

Comment: Oh, yeah `⌘ + L` changes the focus to the address bar.